# What error trigger the Oops, couldn't load error in kik web app

Tags: kik

I am trying to integrate my app into kik, but for a specific action I fall in an error page that says:

> Oops, couldn't load. Please try again later.

This panel looks like a kik panel with my app logo at the top

But everything is OK, If I try my app in Chrome with `Kik plugin` it works well. In fact my app creates an iframe and load it then we use `postMessage` to communicate between parent and `iframe`. I put some logs and it seems that everything is OK. Iframe is loaded and send message to parent with postmessage. But when I am in kik, the 'couldn't load' message appears and stops my app.

Does someone know what cause this panel to appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem.

The problem is the combination of loading an iframe after doing browser history manipulation. Since there is no back button in Kik you can just do the page updates without updating the browser history and this will solve your problem.

I use this line to detect Kik and, if detected, ignore browser history updates:

```
if (!kik.enabled) {
    //We are not running in Kik so we can do browser history manipulation here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Websites in the Kik browser must be single-page applications. The error screen shows up when the website either fails to load or tries to navigate elsewhere.

Is your website doing any navigation? Also, is there a place where we could take a look at the code?

Comment: my app does not navigate, it change the history of navigator but without a real navigation. By the way it is working on android versin of Kik. Only iOS give me this error.

Comment: you can try to reproduce by opening following link in kik: 
staging-ut.urturn.com/kik
Basically you will have a big red button you can click on. On android it open an editor where you can add bubble on a picture. On iphone, it display the error dialog.
it is just a prototype so you cannot really post(it is not implemented now). I just give you this url to allow you to test the open editor feature that is broken on iphone.

Comment: @JulienBachmann On iPhone version of Kik there's a known issue that doesn't allow changing history stack changes. You could try using hash part of your URL to keep track of the current page, e.g. example.com/#my/path instead of example.com/my/path EDIT: Also make sure you are running the latest version of Kik, it had a lot of web related issues resolved